# How to fastly build a graph with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

In order to use PyStruct to perform image segmentation (by means of inference [1]), I first need to build a graph whose nodes correspond to pixels and edges are the link between these pixels.

I have thus written a function, which works, to do so:

```
    def create_graph_for_pystruct(mrf, betas, nb_labels):

        M, N = mrf.shape
        b1, b2, b3, b4 = betas

        edges = []
        pairwise = np.zeros((nb_labels, nb_labels))

        # loop over rows
        for i in range(M):

            # loop over columns
            for j in range(N):

                # get rid of pixels belonging to image's borders
                if i!=0 and i!=M-1 and j!=0 and j!=N-1:

                    # get the current linear index
                    current_linear_ind = i * N + j

                    # retrieve its neighborhood (yield a list of tuple (row, col))
                    neigh = np.array(getNeighborhood(i, j, M, N))

                    # convert neighbors indices to linear ones
                    neigh_linear_ind = neigh[:, 0] * N + neigh[:, 1]

                    # add edges
                    [edges.append((current_linear_ind, n)) for n in neigh_linear_ind]


                    mat1 = b1 * np.eye(nb_labels)
                    mat2 = b2 * np.eye(nb_labels)
                    mat3 = b3 * np.eye(nb_labels)
                    mat4 = b4 * np.eye(nb_labels)

                    pairwise = np.ma.dstack((pairwise, mat1, mat1, mat2, mat2, mat3, mat3, mat4, mat4))               



        return np.array(edges), pairwise[:, :, 1:]
```

However, it is slow and I am wondering where I can improve my function in order to speed it up.
[1] https://pystruct.github.io/generated/pystruct.inference.inference_dispatch.html

Comment: A small change that should help : move the mat1,mat2,etc... definition out of the loops, they don't change so redefining them each time is a huge loss of time.

Comment: Indeed, I have done it. However, it does not speed anything up.

Comment: The next big thing would be to remove those for-loops, but I don't realy undestand what your code is doing so I'm not even sure if it can be vectorized...

Comment: The idea is to loop over all pixels of the image, and for each pixel, to retrieve its 8 neighbors.

Comment: An other fix would be to move `pairwise = np.ma.dstack((pairwise, ...` out of your loop and build the whole thing in one time. All the arrays that you stack have to be copied into a new array so as the pairwise array grows each copy will take a bit more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code suggestion that should run much faster (in numpy one should focus on using vectorisation against for-loops). I try to build the whole output in a single pass using vectorisation, I used the helpfull `np.ogrid` to generate xy coordinates.

```
def new(mrf, betas, nb_labels):
    M, N = mrf.shape
    b1, b2, b3, b4 = betas

    mat1,mat2,mat3,mat4 =  np.array([b1,b2,b3,b4])[:,None,None]*np.eye(nb_labels)[None,:,:]
    pairwise = np.array([mat1, mat1, mat2, mat2, mat3, mat3, mat4, mat4]*((M-2)*(N-2))).transpose()

    m,n=np.ogrid[0:M,0:N]

    a,b,c= m[0:-2]*N+n[:,0:-2],m[1:-1]*N+n[:,0:-2],m[2: ]*N+n[:,0:-2]
    d,e,f= m[0:-2]*N+n[:,1:-1],m[1:-1]*N+n[:,1:-1],m[2: ]*N+n[:,1:-1]
    g,h,i= m[0:-2]*N+n[:,2:  ],m[1:-1]*N+n[:,2:  ],m[2: ]*N+n[:,2:  ]

    center_index = e
    edges_index = np.stack([a,b,c,d,f,g,h,i])

    edges=np.empty(list(edges_index.shape)+[2])
    edges[:,:,:,0]= center_index[None,:,:]
    edges[:,:,:,1]= edges_index

    edges=edges.reshape(-1,2)

    return edges,pairwise
```

**Timing and comparison test :**

```
import timeit

args=(np.empty((40,50)), [1,2,3,4], 10)

f1=lambda : new(*args)
f2=lambda : create_graph_for_pystruct(*args)


edges1, pairwise1 = f1()
edges2, pairwise2 = f2()

#outputs are not exactly indentical: the order isn't the the same
#I sort both to compare the results
edges1 = edges1[np.lexsort(np.fliplr(edges1).T)]
edges2 = edges2[np.lexsort(np.fliplr(edges2).T)]


print("edges identical ?",(edges1 == edges2).all())
print("pairwise identical ?",(pairwise1 == pairwise2).all())

print("new : ",timeit.timeit(f1,number=1))
print("old : ",timeit.timeit(f2,number=1))
```

**Output :**

```
edges identical ? True
pairwise identical ? True
new :  0.015270026000507642
old :  4.611805051001284
```

Note: I had to guess what was in the `getNeighborhood` function

Comment: If we except the image borders, the getNeighborhood() function returns a list of 8 tuple (X, Y) corresponding to the 2D coordinates of the neighbors of a given pixel. b1 applies to the two vertical neighbors, b2 to the two horizontal ones, b3 to the two neighbors belonging to the first diagonal and b4 to the two neighbors belonging to the second diagonal.

Comment: Great, that's what I used for the comparison.

Comment: Could you just detail how such a line: m[0:-2]*N+n[:,0:-2] works? While I often use numpy, I am facing some difficulty to understand this because the dimensions seems to be incompatible.

Comment: m[0:-2] and n[:,0:-2] are both 2d arrays with dimensions that are compatible for broadcasting (m is M,1 and n is 1,N) . So numpy automaticaly stretch the first term dimensions from M-2,1 to M-2,N-2 and the second from 1,N-2 to M-2,N-2.

Comment: Indeed, I was just reading the numpy broadcasting tutorial! Thanks